# Одновременное редактирование git

Tags: git

Появился интерес: допустим над проектом трудятся много человек, у них есть git репозиторий. Люди, работающие над определенной фичей, делают это в отдельной ветке, допустим их >1. Как происходит одновременное редактирование? В моем понимании в ветке останется та версия файла, которая была скоммичена позднее остальных, понимаю насколько это глупо, но поясните пожалуйста)

Comment: У каждого кто будет с гитом работать на компьютере будет копия репозитория. Когда будут вноситься изменения и коммититься, то коммиты будут в локальном репозитории. Когда нужно будет изменения добавить в общий удаленный репозиторий (например, на гитхабе, через команду git push), то коммиты из локального репозитория будут добавлены в удаленный репозиторий, это вызовет проверку изменения файлов и если коммиты от разных людей затрагивают разные файлы, не пересекаясь, то все должно пройти хорошо, иначе будет вызван merge и понадобится руками разобраться какие изменения оставить

Comment: @gil9red, а еще в гите есть автомерж

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На `commit` `Git` смотрит как на **список изменений**, которые были произведены. Отсюда следует несколько фактов:

1. **Ветка** - это последовательность коммитов, то есть изменений, которые накладываются одно на другое. Вроде "сначала дописали строку такую-то", потом "изменили строку такую-то".
2. Если вы работаете в ветке, сделав update с удалённого репозитория, и за время вашей работы кто-то уже сделал commit & push туда своих изменений, то ваши изменения вроде "добавилась строка такая-то после такой-то строки" или "изменилась строка такая-то" уже не всегда так просто могут быть закоммичены. Если вы меняли те строки, которые тот человек не трогал, всё смерджится автоматически. Но если тот человек, например, удалил строку, которую вы редактировали, то отредактировать удалённую строку `Git` не сможет. Ваш commit в таком случае описывает изменения относительно не последнего коммита ветки, а относительно того, который вы взяли за основу. Поэтому ваши изменения не могут быть применены к последнему коммиту (другого человека). Возникнет **конфликт**, и надо будет вручную указывать гиту, что именно сделать - удалить эту строку, отредактировать или вообще что-то третье. Пример разрешения конфликта в среде типа Intellij IDEA: [image: Intellij IDEA resolve conflicts]
   Слева - ваши изменения, справа - чужие, посередине - то, что должно получится (это-то вы и редактируете в процессе разрешения конфликта). Синим отмечено то, что было изменено, зелёным (на рисунке нет) - добавлено, а красным - конфликт (видите, один человек добавил один текст, а другой человек добавил другой текст на то же самое место, и в итоге `Git` не знает, какой вариант взять и просит отредактировать вручную). Можно нажимать на стрелочки на полях, чтобы быстро выбрать один из вариантов слева или справа, а можно нажать, а потом ещё отредактировать вручную, если случай сложный.
3. У нас обычно каждый человек работает в своей ветке. Когда соединяют изменения из нескольких веток, возникает ситуация, аналогичная пункту 2: изменения из одной ветки могут конфликтовать с изменениями из другой. Разница только в том, что изменения обоих людей уже есть в общем репозитории `Git`, но в разных ветках.